# Calculate probability with conditional probability ad the p.d.f

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let X random variable with a probability density function (p.d.f) $f(x)$. Let $P(A)$ the probability of event $A$ and $P(A|x)$ the probability of event $A$ given $x$. Then, the following is true:

$P(A) = \int_{0}^{1} P(A|x) f(x) dx$

Why is this true?

Comment: You have to assume that $X$ takes values in $[0,1]$ for this to be true. If this is the case then it follow from definition of $P(A|x)$.

Comment: I know that it should follow from the definition, but in that definition I have the probability of an intersection. I have tried to see the relation but I do not see how to get this. That's why I was asking

Comment: It appears that you are suing the definition of conditional probability for the discrete case. That definition is not applicable here. Do you know that general definition of conditional probabiltiies and expectations?

Comment: Ok, I googled what you are saying and now it makes more sense. My bad, thank you!